# Change title to arXiv paper

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, preprint

I have a preprint in arXiv, which I submitted at the same time I submitted to a journal. This was a couple of months ago. It was rejected by the journal, and after talking to some experts and getting some advice, one of the changes that I want to make is to the title.

All the other changes qualify as a revision, so normally I would just submit the new version to arXiv. Is it possible to also change the title?

Another solution would be to start a new submission with the new title, but it would probably generate some arXiv overlap warnings, besides not looking too professional. I don't want search engines to find different versions of the paper appearing in different circumstances (what I mean is that I really do want all the old versions to be in the same arXiv page).

Finally, I could just keep the old title. It's not dramatically bad, but I feel the new title reflects more correctly the contents of the paper.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is it possible to also change the title?

Yes, you can change the title when submitting a revision.  You'll be presented with the same web page on which you originally entered the title, and you can edit it (along with anything else) in the `Metadata` phase.

> Another solution would be to start a new submission with the new title, but it would probably generate some arXiv overlap warnings, besides not looking too professional.

The arXiv would certainly not allow this if they noticed (when I think they would), and you are right that it would look unprofessional.